# Make div visible after image is loaded

Tags: jquery, css, html, load, visible

On my website, I have an SWF inside a div that overlays my logo png image. I want this div that contains the SWF to appear only after the logo image is loaded using jQuery.

overlay.php includes the SWF code

```
<div id="overlay"><?php include "overlay.php"?></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#header').on('load',function(){
        $('#overlay').css("visibility","visible");
    });
    </script>
```

css:

```
#overlay{
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:2; 
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

header

```
#header{
    background-image:url(logo.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1; 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML and jQuery you have now?

Comment: The CSS properties `visibility` and `display` do different things - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone. Are you sure you don't want `display` here?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event that listens to the load of the image:

```
$('img').on('load',function(){
    $('#overlay').show();
});
```

Of course you need to hide that `div` first and change `img` to the appropriate `id` or `class`. Same with `div`.

If your image is a `background-image` you can try this:

```
$('<img>').attr('src',function(){
    var imgUrl = $('#header').css('background-image');
    imgUrl = imgUrl.substring(4, imgUrl.length-1);
    return imgUrl;
}).load(function(){
    $('#overlay').show();
});
```

Comment: Just edited my first post using your code but it doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#header` is your image (`img` tag)?

Comment: #header is the div that the logo is loaded into using css(background-image), sorry for not mentioning that I used background-image, does it matter though, script wise?

Comment: Ah. I don't think you can do it that way. At least not with the `load` function.

Comment: How about making it visible when the whole document loads instead of the logo? would that work? edit: your new code didn't work for me.

Comment: This works, but a solution to target the background-image div would be appreciated: `jQuery(window).load(function () {
    $('#overlay').css("visibility","visible");
});`